How to filter duplicate object and pushinto new array
I am getting below response from API , i wanted to create new array based on below condition and push result into new array
I wanted to filter out all duplicate objects based on lineId and totalTime
Below Condition to filter
For ex - If lineId is same and Sum of totalTime in both the lineId is more than 744, than need to push this object into new Array.
For ex - In below response , object with lineId 333 is coming twice and their totalTime sum is more than 744,
than i want this object to be pushed into new array.
Can anyone help me to do this.
 const response = [
  {  
      "lineId": "333",
      "oeeCalculations": {
          "others": {
              "totalTime": 744
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "lineId": "333",
      "oeeCalculations": {
          "others": {
              "totalTime": 744
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "lineId": "111",
      "oeeCalculations": {
          "others": {
              "totalTime": 744
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "lineId": "111",
      "oeeCalculations": {
          "others": {
              "totalTime": 744
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "lineId": "1115",
      "oeeCalculations": {
          "others": {
              "totalTime": 200
          }
      }
  }
];

Expected Output
const result = [
    {  
        "lineId": "333",
        "oeeCalculations": {
            "others": {
                "totalTime": 744
            }
        }
    },
{  
        "lineId": "111",
        "oeeCalculations": {
            "others": {
                "totalTime": 744
            }
        }
    }
   
];

I tried below code but its not summing value of totalTime and not working as expected


const foundDuplicateName = response.find((nnn, index) => {
  return response.find((x, ind) => x.lineId === nnn.lineId && x.oeeCalculations.others.totalTime >= 744 && nnn.oeeCalculations.others.totalTime >= 744 && index !== ind)

})
console.log(foundDuplicateName)
<script>
  const response = [{
      "lineId": "333",
      "oeeCalculations": {
        "others": {
          "totalTime": 744
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "lineId": "333",
      "oeeCalculations": {
        "others": {
          "totalTime": 744
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "lineId": "111",
      "oeeCalculations": {
        "others": {
          "totalTime": 744
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "lineId": "111",
      "oeeCalculations": {
        "others": {
          "totalTime": 744
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "lineId": "1115",
      "oeeCalculations": {
        "others": {
          "totalTime": 200
        }
      }
    }
  ];
</script>




I made a snippet and the output is exactly what you post in your "expected ouput"

Whenever I see a requirement like this - I think of using a set of objects which have a suitable comparable or comparator implemented.

@mplungjan, I checked ur code but it is working for single duplicate object, lets assume my array has more than one duplicate objects in that case its failing...i want if my array has multiple duplicate objects thn it will return new array with all duplicate objects..

So please click [edit] and change the input example and expected result accordingly.

@mplungjan, yes just edited ..can u plz review now..

From the given array it finds duplicates based on the mentioned conditions and pushes into a new array keeping in view that only add one duplicate item


const duplicateItems = [];
const alreadyAdded = new Set();

response.forEach((item, index, self) => {
  const totalTime = item.oeeCalculations.others.totalTime;
  if (!alreadyAdded.has(item.lineId)) {
    const duplicate = self.find((nItem, nIndex) =>
      nIndex !== index && nItem.lineId === item.lineId &&
      nItem.oeeCalculations.others.totalTime + totalTime > 744
    );

    if (duplicate) {
      duplicateItems.push(item);
      alreadyAdded.add(item.lineId);
    }
  }
})
console.log(duplicateItems)
<script>
  const response = [{
      "lineId": "333",
      "oeeCalculations": {
        "others": {
          "totalTime": 744
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "lineId": "333",
      "oeeCalculations": {
        "others": {
          "totalTime": 744
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "lineId": "111",
      "oeeCalculations": {
        "others": {
          "totalTime": 744
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "lineId": "111",
      "oeeCalculations": {
        "others": {
          "totalTime": 744
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "lineId": "1115",
      "oeeCalculations": {
        "others": {
          "totalTime": 200
        }
      }
    }
  ];
</script>




Please add some explanation. I made a snippet so we can see it works

From the given array it finds duplicates based on the mentioned conditions and pushes into a new array keeping in view that only add one duplicate item.

Add that explanation to the answer please

You could group the items by lineId and take only the groups/first items of wanted sums.


const
    response = [{ lineId: "333", oeeCalculations: { others: { totalTime: 744 } } }, { lineId: "333", oeeCalculations: { others: { totalTime: 744 } } }, { lineId: "111", oeeCalculations: { others: { totalTime: 744 } } }, { lineId: "111", oeeCalculations: { others: { totalTime: 744 } } }, { lineId: "1115", oeeCalculations: { others: { totalTime: 200 } } }],
    getTime = ({ oeeCalculations: { others: { totalTime } } }) => totalTime,
    result = Object
        .values(Object.groupBy(response, ({ lineId }) => lineId))
        .flatMap(group => group.length !== 1 && group.reduce((t, o) => t + getTime(o), 0) >= 744
            ? group[0]
            : []
        );

console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




A reduce and a filter could do it


const filteredArray = Object.values(
  response.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const { lineId, oeeCalculations: { others: { totalTime } } } = curr;

    acc[lineId] ??= { ...curr, totalTimeSum: 0 }; // Initialize if not already present
    acc[lineId].totalTimeSum += totalTime;

    if (acc[lineId].totalTimeSum > 744) {
      acc[lineId].included = true; // Mark it as valid for inclusion
    }

    return acc;
  }, {})
).filter(item => item.included)
 .map(({ totalTimeSum, included, ...rest }) => rest); // Remove extra fields

console.log(filteredArray);
<script>
const response = [
  { lineId: "333", oeeCalculations: { others: { totalTime: 744 } } },
  { lineId: "333", oeeCalculations: { others: { totalTime: 744 } } },
  { lineId: "111", oeeCalculations: { others: { totalTime: 744 } } },
  { lineId: "111", oeeCalculations: { others: { totalTime: 744 } } },
  { lineId: "1115", oeeCalculations: { others: { totalTime: 200 } } },
];
</script>



